# Upgraded VLC, won't play CAF files

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player, quicktime

I just upgraded to VLC media player 2.0.4 Twoflower on Win 7. It associates itself with .CAF files, but won't play them.

I have quicktime installed, and it will happily play CAF files, so I'm not sure why there is a problem.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

[Core Audio Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.caf) is a container developed by Apple. Thus it's no surprise that it's supported by Quicktime.

I checked VLC's [Features](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html) page and .caf is not listed under supported formats (or at all.) At a guess, it recognizes that it's a container, and that it contains supported media files, but it cannot unpack them.